# nopcommerce trial product with support for recurring payment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, nopcommerce, recurring-billing

Is there a way to configure a nopCommerce product so that when a consumer purchases the product it will be a recurring billing. But during the purchase if they input a coupon code they get 2/3 months free subscription and then the recurring billing cycle starts?

Comment: Did you find the solution? can you please share it with us.

Comment: I have not customized it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to configure a product as recurring product. However, there is nothing out of the box that start recurring billing cycle based on coupon code.. you will need to customize it.

Comment: Any idea how to approach the problem?

Comment: Just configure product as recurring product

Comment: configuring the products as recurring is not the problem. The question was to allow first 2/3 months free subscription and after that charge client for the payment - That is the challenge.

Comment: You need to customize for that. nopCommerce is not built for this.. so this is not available out of the box. You can do that with some customization.

Comment: Okay. Thnx. I will try to share the solution when I implement it.